# Firefox not continuing after response to the OPTIONS request

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, cors, http-options-method

Is there anything wrong with the response to the OPTIONS request?

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Method: POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 21600
Allow:  POST, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:   Fri, 25 Jul 2014 13:01:30 GMT
Server: Werkzeug/0.9.6 Python/2.7.5
```

I get the exact same response to the OPTIONS request in Chrome and it works perfectly fine, whereas Firefox doesn't continue with the AJAX after the response.